# How to install terraform 0.12 in an alpine container with apk?

Tags: docker, terraform, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I want to add `terraform` version `0.12.21` in an alpine container, but I can only add `0.11.0` using `apk`.  If I try to add it as the desired version I get the following error:

```
/ # apk upgrade terraform==0.12.21-r0
OK: 192 MiB in 66 packages
/ # apk add terraform==0.12.21-r0
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  terraform-0.11.0-r0:
    breaks: world[terraform=0.12.21-r0]
```

How do I fix this apk error?

Comment: Use the Terraform Docker image instead.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I havent found an `apk` solution but I can just download the desired binary and replace the existing one with the following in the dockerfile:

```
# upgrade terraform to 0.12.21
RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.21/terraform_0.12.21_linux_amd64.zip
RUN unzip terraform_0.12.21_linux_amd64.zip && rm terraform_0.12.21_linux_amd64.zip
RUN mv terraform /usr/bin/terraform
```

Comment: After doing these commands, running terraform does not work because it cannot be found.

Answer (score 8):

I'm documenting @SantaXL's comment as an answer just to make it easier to find in the future.

```sh
apk add terraform --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
```

This doesn't specifically add version 0.12, as per the question. Instead, it installs the latest version of terraform held in the Alpine repository. Note that this isn't necessarily the latest version of terraform, but it usually is.

Comment: This is the better solution, because it automatically picks the latest stable version.

Comment: Just to be clear, doing this means that you are installing the latest terraform version from the Alpine repository.  So you cannot really choose which terraform version you want, you are bound to be using the one that is in the repository.

Comment: Thanks @Essej -- You're right about the clarification so I've added it to the answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: If need special the version, try this command `apk add terraform=1.2.5-r0 --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community`

Answer (score 1):

For example:

`apk add terraform --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main`

where `3.12` is apk's [branch](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=terraform&branch=v3.12&arch=x86_64)

Comment: The latest would be:
`apk add terraform --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main`
But still, it gives outdated `v0.12.25`

Comment: @VladimirVukanac that's incorrect. Open in your browser `http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main` - outdated 0.12.25. But if you open `http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community`, you've got the latest version. In other words, use `apk add terraform --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community`. Check `repository` column on this site: `https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=terraform&branch=edge&arch=x86_64`

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong during the process, but purely by running this in Dockerfile I got that version. Here is an example: `docker run --rm -it $(echo "FROM alpine\nRUN apk add terraform --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" | docker build -q - ) sh -c "terraform --version"`
The result is:
`Terraform v0.12.25

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 0.13.5. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html`

Comment: Nice! Thanks! This: `docker run --rm -it $(echo "FROM alpine\nRUN apk add terraform --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" | docker build -q - ) sh -c "terraform --version"` gives the latest version: `Terraform v0.13.5`